# Consistency of perturbative theory when some of the first-order terms are smaller than second-order terms?

Tags: cosmology, mathematics, perturbation-theory, calculus, approximations

There is something that always puzzled me with perturbative approaches.

To my understanding perturbative approaches are often qualified in terms of the order of the perturbation considered. For example in the context of [cosmological perturbation theory](https://www.mv.helsinki.fi/home/hkurkisu/CosPer.pdf) several quantities are perturbed: metric, density, pressure... In this regard, do we always have the guarantee that second order terms will ALWAYS be smaller than all first order terms? Or in other words, is the smallest first order term guaranteed to be greater than the biggest second order term? Is that the case in all perturbation theory? And if that's not the case (ie when $n+1$ order terms are greater than $n$ order terms), then what does the order of the perturbation exactly mean? All in all, I think I need a clarification on why it makes sense to classify perturbations by orders.

Answer (score 1):

There is **no general guarantee** that second-order terms will always be smaller than all first-order terms. The validity of the perturbation expansion and the relative importance of each order depend on the specific system and the nature of the perturbation. **It is possible** for higher-order terms to dominate over lower-order terms under certain conditions.

The **assumption** behind perturbation theory is that the perturbation is small enough so that higher-order terms become successively less important. The classification of perturbations by orders refers to the expansion of physical quantities in a series of powers of a **small** parameter, typically denoted as $\epsilon$. The small parameter represents the magnitude of the perturbation **compared to the unperturbed system**. Each order in the expansion corresponds to a different power of $\epsilon$.

In the context of cosmological perturbation theory, the assumption of small perturbations is reasonable because the observed universe is believed to have originated from a nearly homogeneous and isotropic state. The smallness of the perturbations is supported by observational data.

Answer (score 0):

A perturbation series is never generally valid. Rather, there is a range in the parameter space where it is assumed to hold. A typical example is asymptotic freedom in QCD. You can be sure that your perturbation series is reliable for energies high enough to maintain the coupling small. When the energy lower, QCD is no more manageable through perturbation technique and you have to recur to other methods. Indeed, today we use supercomputer to extract reliable results from QCD at lower energies or some EFTs with different degree of trust in them.